# Find the derivative of $y=x^x$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the derivative of $y=x^x$.

My Attempt:
$$y=x^x$$
Taking $\textrm {ln}$ on both sides, we get:
$$\textrm {ln} y= \textrm {ln} x^x$$
$$\textrm {ln} y = x \textrm {ln} x$$

How do I procees further?

Comment: Use the chain rule on $\ln(y)$: the derivative of the inner function is simply $y'$.

Comment: Now implicitly differentiate both sides with respect to x.

Comment: after your last step, differentiate both sides wrt $x$, then you are at the answer

Comment: Or think how you might calculate it $y = e^{x\cdot\log(x)}$.  Now apply a couple of common rules.

Comment: One might think that $(x^x)' = x \cdot x^{x-1}$, since that works for constant powers, but that's not quite right. One might also think that $(x^x)' = \ln(x) x^x$ since that's how it works for constant bases, but that's not quite right either. Amazingly adding these together gives the correct answer: $(x^x)' = x \cdot x^{x-1} + \ln(x) x^x$.

Comment: @AliceRyhl That's the chain rule for $y=y(s(x),t(x))$.

Comment: I suppose the question implicitely implies that $x>0$, since studying the (not defined everywhere) function $y=x^x$ when $x<0$ is a much more difficult task...

Answer (score 4):

Here is an alternative way to do it, without the use of implicit differentiation:

---

One can start by writing:
$$y=x^x=(e^{\ln{x}})^x=e^{x\ln{x}}$$
Hence, it now becomes extremely obvious to apply the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) to obtain:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}(e^{x\ln{x}})=\color{green}{\frac{d}{dx}(x\ln{x})}\cdot e^{x\ln{x}}$$
Now all you need to do is apply the [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule) on the green one.

Answer (score 2):

your start is very good: $$\frac{1}{y}y'=\ln(x)+x\frac{1}{x}$$

Answer (score 2):

Differentiate with respect to $x$ and on right hand side use product rule.

$\frac 1y \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx} x \cdot \ln x + x \cdot \frac{d}{dx} \ln x$

$\frac 1y \frac{dy}{dx} = 1 \cdot \ln x + x \cdot \frac 1x$

$\frac 1y \frac{dy}{dx} = \ln x + 1$

$\frac{dy}{dx} = y(\ln x + 1)$

$\frac{dy}{dx} = x^x(\ln x + 1)$

Answer (score 1):

***Despite being an answer***

Instead of "How do I proceed further?" one may ask as well "How can I preprocess?".

Here's a proposal: Searching for $\,$ x^x $\,$ in $\,$ https://approach0.xyz/search/ $\,$ yields many$^\text{many}$ hits. Ordered by age – or ripeness? – you may choose & click

- [Finding the derivative of $x^x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/146502/316749)
- [Derivative of $x^x$ at $x=1$ from first principles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177774/derivative-of-xx-at-x-1-from-first-principles)
- [Taylor expansion of $x^x-1$ around 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311903/taylor-expansion-of-xx-1-around-1)
- [explaining the derivative of $x^x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/401122/explaining-the-derivative-of-xx)
- [Derivative of $x^x$ and the chain rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1755360/derivative-of-xx-and-the-chain-rule)
- ... and so on

Worthwhile & close to it is
[Is $x^x$ an exponential function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/676641/is-xx-an-exponential-function)
(just having received an upvote).

Still link no. 7
[How effectively to search through MSE resources](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26242/how-effectively-to-search-through-mse-resources)
before posting this one.

Answer (score 0):

Remark that $y = x^x=e^{x \log x}$ and then proceed with the product rule $\frac{dy}{dx} = e^{x \log x} \frac{d}{dx} (x \log x) = x^x (\log x + 1)$.